# Have Sql SMO Delete Database Backup File

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, file, delete-file

I have create a C# application that allows a database to be backed up and restored. It does this by first backing the database up to a local file on the Sql server using:

```
Backup backup = new Backup();
backup.Devices.AddDevice(Path.GetFullPath(backupFilePath), DeviceType.File);
...
backup.SqlBackup(server);
```

And then I create the new database by restoring from the backup file using:

```
Restore restore = new Restore();
restore.Devices.AddDevice(Path.GetFullPath(backupFileToRestoreFrom), DeviceType.File);
...
restore.SqlRestore(server);
```

After the new database has been created I want to delete the temp backup file that we created.  Because I have admin rights on the Sql server box, I can delete the file on the remote server using:

```
File.Delete("\\SqlServer\C$\Backups\BackupFileToDelete.bak")
```

and it works.  However, if somebody else who doesn't have rights on the Sql server box runs the app, it will throw an exception about not having permissions.

So is there a Sql SMO function that I can call to delete the backup file that was created on the remote Sql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete the file using the xp_cmdshell then it will use the rights of the sql server instead of the rights of the person.

For example:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'Del \\SqlServer\C$\Backups\BackupFileToDelete.bak', NO_OUTPUT
```

Here's the reference on [xp_cmdshell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)

The important thing to note from that article is:

> Because malicious users sometimes attempt to elevate their privileges
>   by using xp_cmdshell, xp_cmdshell is disabled by default. Use
>   sp_configure or Policy Based Management to enable it. For more
>   information, see xp_cmdshell Server Configuration Option.

Comment: This seems like it would be a great solution, however I just checked with our DBAs and they are not willing to turn it on :( Any other options? +1 though, and will mark this as the answer if I don't receive any other options that work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use SQLCLR, which is more secure than using xp_cmdshell. There's even [a CodePlex project call SQLCLR File Functions](http://nclsqlclrfile.codeplex.com/) that has the functionality written as stored procs for me.  I think I'm going to see if I can convince our DBAs to go this route. The downside is that I believe the sprocs that this creates would need to be installed on every existing and new SQL Server that gets created; not much different than having to enable xp_cmdshell on every server though I guess.